# PYTHON, Midpoint Method, TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, arrays, floating-point, ode

I am trying to develop an iterative method for approximating first order ODE. i keep running into the error of float cannot be intepreted as an integer  I've tried numerous solutions such as changing N to an int like

N = int(N)

or h = int((b-a)/N)

or ive tried h = (b-a)//N

but even when I try other solutions I end up getting floating point error division: divide by zero. I know the code isn't that intense but I'm stumped trying to change the input to accept N as in integer and not a float so that the array can be properly iterated.

Here is my code:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

at:

```
File "/Users/luciusanderson/Documents/Numerical Analysis 
II/ODE_Approx_methods.py", line 61, in Midpoint_meth
y = np.zeros((N+1,))      #array to hold Midpoint Method approximated y 
values




def Midpoint_meth(def_fn, a, b, N, ya):

"""
    Test the Midpoint Method to solve
    initial value problem y'=f(t,y) with t in [a,b] and y(a) = ya.
    Step size h is computed according to input number of mesh points N
"""

f = def_fn #input definining function


h = (b-a)/N # developing step size h, from input values divided by N




t = np.arange(a, b+h, h) #array intialized to hold mesh points t
y = np.zeros((N+1,))      #array to hold Midpoint Method approximated y values

y[0] = ya   #intial condition 

#iterative method

for  i in range(0, N):

    tau = t[i]      #current mesh point t 
    w = y[i]        #current value y(t)


    # next iteration using midpoint method 
    y[i + 1] = w + h*f(tau + h/2.0, w + h*f(tau, w /2.0))


return (t, y)

############ Example #1 Given Points 

N_mdeul1 = 20.0  # number of mesh points
a_mdeul1 = 0.0 # left end point of interval [a,b]
b_mdeul1 = 2.0 # right end point of interval [a,b]
ya_mdeul1 = 0.5 # initial value y(a)

# defining function and true solution of function #1
def_fn_mdeul1 = exmp_fn.exmp1_def_fn
sol_mdeul1 = exmp_fn.exmp1_sol


# run Euler's method from ODE_Approx_methods for example #1

(t_mdeul1,w_mdeul1) = ODE_Approx_methods.Midpoint_meth(def_fn_mdeul1,
```

Comment: can you post the entire traceback?

Comment: and include a runnable piece of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hacked out what I think are the relevant parts.

```
def Midpoint_meth(def_fn, a, b, N, ya):

    """
        Test the Midpoint Method to solve
        initial value problem y'=f(t,y) with t in [a,b] and y(a) = ya.
        Step size h is computed according to input number of mesh points N
    """
    print(type(N))
    f = def_fn #input definining function


    h = (b-a)/N # developing step size h, from input values divided by N


    t = np.arange(a, b+h, h) #array intialized to hold mesh points t
    y = np.zeros((N+1,))      #array to hold Midpoint Method approximated y values

    y[0] = ya   #intial condition 

    #iterative method

    for  i in range(0, N):

        tau = t[i]      #current mesh point t 
        w = y[i]        #current value y(t)


        # next iteration using midpoint method 
        y[i + 1] = w + h*f(tau + h/2.0, w + h*f(tau, w /2.0))


    return (t, y)

############ Example #1 Given Points 

N_mdeul1 = 20.0  # number of mesh points
a_mdeul1 = 0.0 # left end point of interval [a,b]
b_mdeul1 = 2.0 # right end point of interval [a,b]
ya_mdeul1 = 0.5 # initial value y(a)



# run Euler's method from ODE_Approx_methods for example #1

(t_mdeul1,w_mdeul1) = Midpoint_meth(1, a_mdeul1, b_mdeul1, ya_mdeul1, N_mdeul1)
```

I am getting the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-51b398a6cbbd> in <module>()
     43 # run Euler's method from ODE_Approx_methods for example #1
     44 
---> 45 (t_mdeul1,w_mdeul1) = Midpoint_meth(1, a_mdeul1, b_mdeul1, ya_mdeul1, N_mdeul1)
     46 

<ipython-input-31-51b398a6cbbd> in Midpoint_meth(def_fn, a, b, N, ya)
     20     #iterative method
     21 
---> 22     for  i in range(0, N):
     23 
     24         tau = t[i]      #current mesh point t

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Which made me see that in your call:

```
(t_mdeul1,w_mdeul1) = Midpoint_meth(1, a_mdeul1, b_mdeul1, ya_mdeul1, N_mdeul1)
```

The 4th argument (N in your function call), which is the variable

```
ya_mdeul1
```

is

```
ya_mdeul1 = 0.5
```

Definitely not an int

Comment: Is there any way I can change the formatting of the intial value (ya_mdeul1) to be an int? such as ya_mdeul1 = int(0.5) ?

Comment: I am assuming that is where your problem is.  int(0.5) turns the number into zero, which is probably why you are getting the divide by zero answers elsewhere.

Comment: the more important question, is what is the N in your function, why why would it ever be set as a float.

Comment: Are you saying in the for loop N is being looked at as a float?

Comment: I am saying that you are setting N to a float when you call your function here: Midpoint_meth(1, a_mdeul1, b_mdeul1, ya_mdeul1, N_mdeul1)  because you set ya_mdeul1 = 0.5 which is a float

Comment: look at the order of your variables, and how you are calling them

Comment: I didn't even see that. Thanks a ton

Comment: np.  for future reference, add only the code required to reproduce the problem, it is easier for people to help that way.  Also, marked as answered so other people do not spend their time.